# wpf button background hover color

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, styles, hover

I'm trying to change the background colour of a button's style in xaml on hover
This is my current approach, but it doesn't work. The default hover colour is being used

```
<Style x:Key="AtStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource AtBlue}" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,6" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18.667" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I've seen other solutions that say that you need to override the Control template to achieve this, but those solutions also require you define the border and the content as well which seems unnecessary. What is the minimal approach to defining a hover state in Xaml?

Answer (score 11):

I have created simple style based button based on your requirement,

XAML

```
<Style  TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="Blue" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
          Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
          Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="White" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="bg"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderThickness="2"
                BorderBrush="White">
          <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                   Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Red"
                    TargetName="bg" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This style is too simple. It breaks access keys, it doesn't even support disabled state. It is also wrong, as alignment properties on `ContentPresenter` should use content alignment properties.

Comment: @Athari:Thanks for your suggestion,yes it is to simple.they need to include Triggers for Disabled and keyboardfocuesd states.

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at the template of the default button style for Aero theme:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
    <theme:ButtonChrome Name="Chrome"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding Button.IsDefaulted}"
            RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
            RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <ContentPresenter
                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
    </theme:ButtonChrome>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Chrome" Property="RenderDefaulted" Value="True"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Chrome" Property="RenderPressed" Value="True"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

As you can see, the mouse-over and pressed colors are defined as bindings on the `ButtonChrome`'s properties `RenderMouseOver` and `RenderPressed`. The way `ButtonChrome` is designed, they take priority over any values from the `Background` property. Therefore, unfortunately, the only way to override background color of a clicked or highlighted button is to override its template.

Comment: This example does not work... Why you think this is a better answer than the other one? That one is working...

Comment: @Bondye This answer is not supposed to "work", it is supposed to answer the question "why" and give directions how to solve the problem completely. The accepted answer "works", but in a very limited number of cases, and is not helpful if anything more complex is necessary. More detailed analysis is in my comment to another question. TL;DR: don't merely copy-paste; try to understand and to do it yourself.